# When are C# objects garbage collected when using Embedded Mono (libmono-2.0)

Tags: c#, c, mono, interop

I am using libmono to call a C# object from my C code. Some of the methods for that object take Object parameters. So for instance, to call an object with an array parameter, i use

```
MonoArray *data = mono_array_new(domain, mono_get_byte_class(), len);
```

and then call `mono_runtime_invoke` with the object and parameters listed. How do i know that the array isn't garbage collected in between `mono_array_new` and `mono_runtime_invoke`?

Comment: Post the C code, and the full C# signature of the method you want to use.  Be sure before you hit submit the calling convention is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you keep the data pointer as a local variable in the function where invoke() is called, it won't be garbage collected. Or, since it needs to be stored in the argument array for mono_runtime_invoke(), make sure that array is a local variable (stack or register allocated. A function argument is equivalent to a local variable).

If you need to store a managed object in any other place, like a static variable, a thread local, somewhere in malloced memory etc., then you need to keep a reference to it yourself, for example using the mono_gchandle_new() API.